fiware pep proxy port is not open
I followed here git install process.
But not open 3003 port.
What is reason not open port?
I don't understand below part on the git.
//Duplicate config.template in config.js and configure app host there.
config.app_host = 'www.google.es'; // Hostname to forward authenticated requests
config.app_port = '80'; // Port where the HTTP server is running

What mean above process?
Could you explain detail?
below file is already exist git clone.
config.js.template
and I made file below like a above process.
config.template
vi config.template
###################
#!/usr/bin/env node
const config = {};

// Used only if https is disabled
config.pep_port = 3003;


config.app_host = 'www.google.es'; // Hostname to forward authenticated requests
config.app_port = '80'; // Port where the HTTP server is running

module.exports = config;
###################

and I excuted below command
$npm install
$ npm start

> fiware-pep-proxy-test@8.3.0 start
> node ./bin/www

Referencely not remain any error log in node or npm.
Please tell me cause.
Thank you.

The full documentation for the PEP-Proxy can be found here: https://fiware-pep-proxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin_guide/ - config.pep_port, config.app_host and config.app_port can be amended either by amending the config.js file or by injecting Docker environment variables as done in this example here: https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.PEP-Proxy/tree/NGSI-v2
pep_port is the port to use if HTTPS is disabled - which is obviously only something you'd want to do in a test environment. Normally you'd want to force HTTPS, but for local development having the PEP running on a random port without any certificates is a reasonable workaround. Port 3003 is just a random port number.
If you follow this tutorial example, you should be aware that the configuration is designed for learning only and not for production deployment and will not scale. A proper architecture has been sacrificed to keep the narrative focused on the learning goals, they are just used to deploy everything onto a single Docker machine and aslo contain various obvious security flaws - passwords in plain text, no load balancing, no use of HTTPS and so on. to avoid the need of multiple machines, generating certificates, encrypting secrets and so on, purely so that a single docker-compose file can be read as an example to build on.
When deploying to a production environment, refer to the Helm Repository for FIWARE Components in order to scale up to a proper architecture: https://github.com/FIWARE/helm-charts/
